# How to use WebAssembly (wasm) code in a Web Worker?

Tags: javascript, web-worker, webassembly

Currently, a Web Worker is instantiated thus:

```
let worker = new Worker('worker.js');
```

The browser then fetches `worker.js` and it can start responding to messages.

I'd like to implement my worker's functionality using WebAssembly. Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
let worker = new Worker('worker.wasm');
```

But I'm pretty sure that's not possible. The most obvious alternative is to have `worker.js` fetch `worker.wasm` and compile and run it. But this means we fetch one script (`worker.js`) whose only job is to fetch and run another script (`worker.wasm`). This feels gross to me. And so my question: is there a cleaner way of using WebAssembly within a Web Worker, which won't introduce an extra fetch step?

Comment: _"And so my question: is there a cleaner way of using WebAssembly within a Web Worker, which won't introduce an extra fetch step?"_ What is purpose of using `Worker` in the first instance if `Worker` is not intended to be used? No actual problem statement exists at Question.

Comment: @guest271314 one benefit is that wasm would be run in a different thread

Comment: Probably you could put the wasm in a SharedArrayBuffer, didn't try it out but I could imagine that with a SharedArrayBuffer no copying is needed.

Comment: This repository contains a couple of examples for using web workers with Wasm (compiled from Rust): https://github.com/sgasse/wasm_worker_interaction

Answer (score 2):

You can `postMessage` a `WebAssembly.Module` to a `Worker`. You'd therefore compile `foo.wasm` in your main script, and then `postMessage` it, which implementations are expected to optimize so as not to recompile or duplicate code (though at this time not all implementations do so). You then merely need your worker to instantiate.

One thing you need for instantiate is an `importObject`, and what you pass in needs to be resident to that worker! So even if you could say "new worker with this `.wasm`" you wouldn't have a way to specify the `importObject`.

This is documented [in structured clone](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/JS.md#structured-clone-of-a-webassemblymodule), which also affects IndexDB.

Comment: I'm not sure this actually works. When I try to send a wasm `Module` in `postMessage` I get this: example.js:54 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': () => resolve(Module) could not be cloned.
    at http://localhost:8000/example.js:13702:31
    at <anonymous>

Comment: I cleaned up my code and am using `WebAssembly.compile` to produce a module. I then try to send it via `postMessage` but I get this: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': An object could not be cloned.

Comment: That was under Chrome 60. Chrome 62 gives Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': #<Module> could not be cloned. Firefox 57.0b14 seems to work.

Comment: That sounds like a Chrome bug.

Comment: https://github.com/nodeca/pica/blob/3.0.6/index.js#L322 wasm object transfer worked for me in chrome. But i dropped this in next version of package. Browserify + webworkify are good enougth (it creates ww src on the fly from modules in main thread). IMHO additional compile step in ww for small modules is cheap and preferable to keep things simple.